# How do I write a jquery selector to match p tags that have no closing p tag?

Tags: jquery, selector

I am trying to write a selector that selects everything within a p
However, the HTML I am trying to select from does not close the p, instead it uses a /br like this:

```
<p>Some Text Here</br>
<p>Some more text</br>
```

When I use a selector that is just p, it selects Some Text Here Some more Text, not the two individual elements.

Is there any way to write a selector that will match both elements??

Note: I am NOT in control of this HTML, but yet I need to parse it

Comment: it isn't possible to select just the opening p html because the p element consists of both the opening tag and the closing tag. YOu can however select the text you want using .contents() and filtering to the first text node.

Comment: jQuery doesn't support this as it is not valid code. I would recommend you use valid html then jQuery will work for what you need.

Comment: @pst, actually researched it after typing that, but not quickly enough to avoid being chastised.  i stand corrected.

Comment: Kevin B: Is there a way to filter the contents in a selector to say "the contents until br>"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it's sloppy markup, the browser will parse it just fine as it is. Since paragraphs can't be nested, the browser will put an implicit closing tag before the second p and at the end of the body for the second p.

http://jsfiddle.net/KpJNH/1/

Comment: +1.  op should update the html, but it will work as is.  the difficulty was that you were selecting the text of both `<p>` tags at the same time.  take a look at the fiddle to see the difference.